# Is there a way to Symfony2 sending session cookies only for authenticated user

Tags: php, symfony, session

found only

```
stateless:  true
```

and this disable all cookies.
I want use cookies only for log in users. 
Is it possible?

Comment: There is no session cookie until user hit a form. Just remove cookie after logout and you are cookie free.

Comment: Yes You have right :)